# Cannot open chrome for a minute after startup

Tags: startup

So, i've started my computer, then started chrome. But it takes long, and there's Googleupdate.exe in my process everytime i start chrome or startup.

I've also noticed that there's no 2 computers thingy in my taskbar(network) and there's no Windows Security Alert in my taskbar(red shield x).

So i've waited, and then chrome starts up. Security Alert and network thingy is in my taskbar.

I don't wanna waste my time anymore, how do i fix this?

Comment: Sounds like your computer's just slow to start, unless it only started happening recently. In any case, this is **off-topic for StackOverflow** as it's not about a specific programming problem.

Answer (score -1):

May be due to cookies, It's been refreshing. Better clear your chrome browser cookies and restart the browser for fast speed chrome or chromium.